# Ability to easily switch between directories in different areas

Tags: shell, directory, cd-command

I'm doing something where I'm frequently changing between two directories far away from each other in the system's file tree.

Is there anyway I can assign some kind of short name to each one for use with the `cd` command so that I can type `cd directoryA` and `cd directoryB` for example, instead of repeatedly typing `cd C:/A/Really/Long/File/Path/Name/Makes/My/Fingers/Hurt`?

Comment: You can have 2 terminals, each opened in one directory. You can use pushd and popd. You can use aliases And you can use `cd -` (and possibly other options)

Comment: Another option: symlink them both as subdirectories of the same place

Comment: this might also help you out https://github.com/wting/autojump

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use shell variables:

```
da=/really/long/path/to/directory/a
db=/other/really/long/path/to/directory/b

cd $da
cd $db
```

The advantage of this method is that you can use $da and $db in place of file paths in any command, for example:

```
cp $da/file1 $db/file2
```

Comment: And, if you happen to already be in one of the directories you want to save (perhaps by having used [TAB] to get there), you can do `da=\`pwd\`` to save the current directory in the variable.

Comment: I've come back to this question after a long time, because having more experience now, I feel that this is a better answer for new people encountering this question, for the reasons you mentioned. I've marked this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 12):

For *exactly* two directories, use `cd -`

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cd /var/tmp
$ cd -
/tmp
$ cd -
/var/tmp
$ cd -
/tmp
$
```

Comment: While this solves my current problem, it also raises the obvious question. What about for more than two directories?

Comment: You could use `pushd`. See `help pushd` or the bash manual.

Comment: This solves your current problem.  If it raises another question for you... post that question.  The simplest answer to the above specific question is the approach detailed here, i.e. `cd -`.  The simplest answer to there being three directories will be different.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there anyway I can assign some kind of short name to each one

Yes of course, with the `alias` command:

```
alias directoryA='cd /path/to/directoryA'
```

Then use `directoryA` as an alias for your `cd` command. It's really that straightforward ;)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thanks. However, a few things: What is the lifespan of this alias? Is it then defined forever? How would I disable an alias?

Comment: @Airhead It's defined during that terminal's lifespan, to have that alias defined for each subsequent terminal you would need to include the `alias` command in your startup script (ex: `.bashrc`). I `source` a file named `.bash_aliases` in my `.bashrc`, I believe this is a common and advised practice. Use `unalias` to *disable* an alias.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Use a different shell than Bash for interactive work. I use [Fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) that allows me to type

```
$ cd /u/sh/sounds
```

and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Afterwards the command line reads

```
$ cd /usr/share/sounds/
```

No need to define any aliases, just write enough for it to become unique.

Comment: you still need all the slashes, though, don't you?

Comment: The US keyboard layout makes typing a `/` really easy, there is a dedicated key for it.

Comment: it's still much slower than typing an alias or environment variable for very commonly used folders.

Comment: Yes, for one path I just have defined a variable and just to `cd $MA`. This only works since there are no spaces in the path, otherwise it would have to be `cd "$MA"` in Bash.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a directory (or any file) an abbreviated name by creating a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to it. A symbolic is a directory entry that doesn't actually contain any data, but points to another path where the actual data is to be found. Operating on the directory entry (e.g. create, rename, delete) manipulates the symbolic link, while operating on the content (e.g. read, write, `cd` and `ls` for a directory, etc.) operates on the target of the link. For example, create a symbolic link with the [`ln` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html):

```
ln -s /A/Really/Long/File/Path/Name/Makes/My/Fingers/Hurt ~/hurt
```

Then `cd ~/hurt` is mostly equivalent to `/A/Really/Long/File/Path/Name/Makes/My/Fingers/Hurt`. It's mostly equivalent because the shell remembers and displays `~/hurt` as the current working directory; if you want the shell to forget about the symbolic link, use `cd -P ~/hurt`.

If you very often change to subdirectories of a particular directory, you can use the [`CDPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-CDPATH) variable. When you run `cd` with a relative path (i.e. an argument that doesn't start with `/`, either explicitly or via an abbreviation such as `~` or a variable whose value starts with `/`), the shell tries to change to a subdirectory of each element of `CDPATH` in turn until it finds one that exists. If you use `CDPATH`, you are strongly recommended to put `.` (the current directory) first, otherwise an innocent-looking `cd subdir` could make you jump to a completely unrelated location.

```
CDPATH=.:/A/Really/Long/File/Path/Name/Makes/My
cd Fingers/Hurt
```

You can also define abbreviations inside the shell as variables. Use `$` in front of the variable name to use its value. Note that if the variable's value contains special characters such as spaces, you need double quotes when using it (unless you use zsh or fish as your shell).

```
hurt=/A/Really/Long/File/Path/Name/Makes/My/Fingers/Hurt
cd $hurt
spaced='/A/Really Long/File Path Name/Makes My Fingers/Hurt'
cd "$spaced"
```

In bash [the `cdable_vars` option makes this easier on the fingers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354649).

If a component in the path is long, use completion. If your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key isn't worn out, you're doing it wrong. For best results, avoid having many file names that have a few letters in common at the beginning, and avoid starting file names with hard-to-type characters such as uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

You can install **autojump**.

so you can type "`j directoryA<enter>`" or "`j dire<tab>`" to select in multi directories.

Comment: This is the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use the `cdable_vars` shell option to do something similar:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ mkdir -p /tmp/i/j/k/k/l/m/n/o
$ h=/tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ o=/tmp/i/j/k/k/l/m/n/o
$ shopt -s cdable_vars
$ cd /tmp
$ cd h
$ pwd
/tmp/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
$ cd o
$ pwd
/tmp/i/j/k/k/l/m/n/o
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Apparix**](http://micans.org/apparix/). It allows you to define bookmarks for your directories. Then jumping to and fro between them, once configured, is as easy as

```
to foo
# Goes to /this/is/a/complex/path/for/foo

to bar
# Goes to /a/completely/unrelated/path/for/bar

to foo subdir
# Goes to /this/is/a/complex/path/for/foo/subdir
```

Etc. And all the shortcuts and subdirectories are auto-completed.

It’s an immensely powerful, highly underrated tool. I find it performs better than alternatives such as autojump because it gives the user more control.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just moving directly between two directories, `cd -` will take you to the last working directory.

Answer (score 0):

`pushd` is the bash command for this purpose.

Read the section on how to use it in `man bash` to learn how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about bash (I don't use it if I can possibly avoid doing so), but in tcsh & other shells, you could simply use the history mechanism.  So you would type e.g. "cd /" and ctl-UpArrow to scroll back through all commands to cd to paths starting at root.

Note that this works for any command,  not just cd.  You just need the first few characters of whatever you want to scroll back to.